# Bioconductor, R versions and local installs

Tags: r, local, bioconductor

I need to install Bioconductor.  I'm trying to get this on one of two systems; I'm under a real time crunch and every single workaround has failed.

System 1: Centos 7 server, R v3.4.2 (can't get R v3.5.0 because the server doesn't have the libreadline-dev package; a separate issue)

- Run `source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")`

  - Problem: I cannot install this as root.  I can't find a way to install it locally.  Adding `lib="/my/local/dirpath"` to source() function is not correct syntax, and from reading the manpage on source() I can't figure it out.

System 2: My personal machine, running Win10 and I also have the Linux subsystem. I updated R v3.3.1 to 3.5.0 using "installr" package.

- 1. Run source() command as above.

     - Latest error: `lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library is not writeable`.  Want to use a personal library?  Yes I do.  I have one I already created.  I added it to .libPaths.  I don't know how to add it to source() function.
- 2. Previous error: BiocInstaller version is too old ...

     - For that error, I tried following the instructions on the [Bioconductor install page](https://www.bioconductor.org/install/). `remove.packages("BiocInstaller", lib=.libPaths())` and then run source(...) again.  Then I got the error "BiocInstaller" package doesn't exist. `install.packages("BiocInstaller", lib="my/local/dirpath")` told me `package 'BiocInstaller' is not available (for R version 3.5.0)`.

I have gotten that same error when I try to install BiocInstaller the same way on my Centos system (package not available for R version 3.4.2).

For the love of all that is good and holy, would some kind and knowledgeable person please give me some advice here?  It's been two days, the clock is ticking, and I'm at my wit's end.  I feel like I've tried everything. I'd be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System 1. Ensure .libPaths()[1] is a writable location.

System 2. Part 1. Is your writable location in the first position of .libPaths()? Is there an existing version of BiocInstaller in a non-writable location? Part 2. 'BiocInstaller' is from the Bioconductor repository, not CRAN; you would need to know the correct location of the Bioconductor repository for the version you are trying to use. The best way to find that is to get the source() command to work. `biocLite()` is a wrapper around `install.packages()`, and the key line in the documentation `?install.packages()` is

> ```
> lib: character vector giving the library directories where to
>       install the packages.  Recycled as needed.  If missing,
>       defaults to the first element of '.libPaths()'.
> ```

Ask instead on https://support.bioconductor.org (here's the cross-post, I think https://support.bioconductor.org/p/109184/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to Bioconductor support.  I will ask there.  On System 1 & 2, .libPaths() does contain a writable location (a local directory), but it also contains the root directories that are automatically setup.  I did .libPaths( c(.libPaths(), "/my/local/path") and then that's the path I use with install.packages.

Comment: For Part 2 - "the best way ...is to get the source() command to work." 
 That's what I was thinking.  Hopefully, I'll find some help over at the support community you so kindly linked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: `.libPaths( c(.libPaths(), "/my/local/path"))` puts the writable directory after any existing directories; try the other way around...

Comment: That basically fixed it (major "duh" moment).  It turns out I think temporary VPN and Wifi connectivity issues were also complicating things (the former is typical, the latter not). Later I was able to correct a few minor things on my own thanks to Stack Overflow posts.  Mostly with help of your comments, so I wanted to say thanks for your posts overall here. They are concise, yet clear and complete - a real asset to this site.